# android studio 2.0 logcat spammed by deconnection

Tags: android, android-studio

My `Android Studio` keeps being spammed by some sort of debug message ever since I upgraded to 2.0

```
[ 05-17 17:08:32.896    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection

[ 05-17 17:08:34.896    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection

[ 05-17 17:08:36.910    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection

[ 05-17 17:08:38.912    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection

[ 05-17 17:08:40.909    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection

[ 05-17 17:08:42.918    81:   81 D/         ]
Socket deconnection
```

and it keeps going and going.
It gets really spam happy whenever my app starts pushing data to a server.  The data is making it across so I'm not sure whats happening.

I've added this to my logcat filter to try and get rid of it but it did not work: ^(?!WifiStateMachine|ConnectivityService|ConnectivityManager|dalvikvm|IInputConnectionWrapper)

Does anyone know how to get rid of this? its making it really hard to debug my app and keep track of my logs.

Thank you for your time

**EDIT**
Thank you to a comment that pointed out that `Genymotion` can be pointed to the Android SDK and use THAT `adb.exe` which will stop this stupid spam
Under the genymotion main app, click options -> ADB -> custom android SDK
point to /AppData/Local/Android/sdk
bingo!

Comment: Same problem here. This crap is everywhere.

Comment: Maybe there should be used word "flooded", not "spammed".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using Genymotion by chance? I had the same error after updating to version 2.7.0. By default, Genymotion uses its own adb.exe , located in the Genymotion\tools folder. I realized that three different instances of adb.exe are running at same time - one in Android\sdk\platform-tools folder and two in the Genymotion folder.

I changed the configuration of Genymotion to use the system adb.exe and the Socket deconnection error disappeared. I have Android Studio 2.1.2.

If you are using a real device, it might be a cable connection problem. In all cases, it is good to check if no different adb.exe instance is running simultaneously.

P.S. The Socket deconnection instant error appeared again, this time only on tablet AVD and only in landscape orientation.
Should you experience the same, close all open applications and open Network and sharing center - change adapter settings. Right click on Virtualbox host only network - Properties, uncheck all other and leave only Virtualbox NDIS6 Driver, TCP/IPv4 and the two link - layers checked (I suspect the TCP/IPv6 was the cause). Then reboot the OS.

EDIT
There is a second cause for the "socket deconnection" error. If it persists after changing the default ADB , exit Genymotion , wait a while , and open Virtualbox as standalone program. Choose your AVD - Settings - Network.  If it is set to "Host only adapter" , change it to NAT Network - Name NatNetwork (NAT or Bridged might work too) .
It seems that Genymotion forces the network adapter to "Host only" again at every startup and NAT is second adapter. Usually it works fine, but if the deconnection error occurs , the change to NAT Network makes it disappear.

Comment: I am using Genymotion.
it only happens with this.  Could it be possible to turn Genymotion adb.exe off and force it to use Android studio's instead?

Comment: Yes , Genymotion can be started standalone (not from Android Studio or Eclipse plugin) . It usually creates two red icons on the desktop - one for shell commands and one for configuration and AVD creation. If you start from the second one , click on "Settings" and then on "ADB" tab.

Comment: Then choose the second option "Use custom SDK Tools" and browse for the SDK adb.exe - usually in /User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk folder in Windows . If you don't have the desktop icons, you can run genymotion.exe directly from its folder.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Virtual Device again solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Genymotion app from 2.7.1 to 2.7.2 solved for me.

The ADB settings still the same (using ADB from android-sdk) and I didn't have to update the Virtual Device.

Comment: I'm using Genymotion 2.7.2 and all the same having similar problem

Comment: same with 2.8.1. And it forces its network to "host only", if I change it it won't start

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @Helmwag, the problem may be in ADB but not only of Genymotion, but the default SDK too.

In my case, I switched ADB from Genymotion to Android SDK some time ago, because of some other problem. I didn't notice tons of debug messages at first.

Today I finally tired of them and decided to get rid of these network messages. Switching the Genymotion back from the Android SDK ADB to the inner Genymotion ADB solved my problem.

Probably, it is the result of some inner mechanisms inside ADB and emulator but, strangely, the problem may be hidden from the both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started experiencing this again. However, I sort of expected it. Stupid me used Sleep, which meant that I had to restart PC (a few hours later) but it came back as woken up. In doing so **Virtual box** requested updates 3 times (if I recall # correctly) and this, from experience, resets network adapters and, I believe why in this situation I started getting these errors which I haven't had for some time now.

I have **GenyMotion 2.8.1**. I don't think GenyMotion's or Android ADB makes much difference (I've been using the latter for some time, but more recently upgraded to Windows 10 and only just realised now that I was using Genymotion's, just changed to Android's).

I have a relatively powerful PC (FX8350 and 32Gb ram). I recently upgraded from 16 to 32 and the improvement in reliability of startiing GenyMotion Devices without a hang since this upgrade, is why I suspect that a)(ii) below appears to make a difference.

My solution, which I normally rigorously follow and which appears to cure other annoying behaviors (e.g. continually disconnecting all devices (*I normally have a real device (or more) and also a GenyMotion device (sometimes more)*)) is to :-

**a)** **(i)** Have ALL real Android devices connected and **(ii)** also have as few programs/applications running as possible (*this appears to provide a far better chance of GenyMotion devices not hanging*)

**b)** Start **GenyMotion** and wait a while (a minute or so) and then start the required GenyMotion Device. If more than one than one at a time (I've had 5 running at once but not recently) then only start a new one when the predecessor has fully started (i.e. the Home Screen is displayed).

**c)** When the **GenyMotion** device has, or devices have, started successfully then start **Android Studio**.

Comment: that's a bit of a Frankenstein method but it might work

Comment: doesn't work. I think the problem is this ugly google's abortion - Android Studio. Everything Google touches become ugly. I love jetbrains, but Google raped idea (not perfect IDE though) and we have... ASS

Comment: I believe that as of SDK Platform tools 25.04 that things have bee flipped and you now have to start AS before starting genymotion devices. It's also a little more complex as you appear to need to use RUN before if you have any real devices attached. If you want to also use Android Device Monitor you also appear to need to have this started before as well.

Comment: Neither launching AS before nor after Genymotion does solve the problem.